# Cosmos installation fails

Tags: c#, visual-studio, puppet, fiware, cosmos

I'm trying to install locally cosmos.

I followed the guide instructions and successfully execute puppet script on slave machines.
I've a problem executing puppet script on the master machine.

The script fails. Here is the content of puppet.err log file:

```
[1;31mError: /Stage[main]/Cosmos::Setup/Exec[cosmos-setup]: Failed to call refresh: /opt/pdi-cosmos/cosmos-admin/cosmos-admin setup returned 255 instead of one of [0][0m
[1;31mError: /Stage[main]/Cosmos::Setup/Exec[cosmos-setup]: /opt/pdi-cosmos/cosmos-admin/cosmos-admin setup returned 255 instead of one of [0][0m
```

**EDIT**

This is the output running manually `cosmos-admin setup`

```
15:16:00,894 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback.groovy]
15:16:00,894 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback-test.xml]
15:16:00,895 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Found resource [logback.xml] at [jar:file:/opt/pdi-cosmos/cosmos-admin/lib/play_2.10-2.2.2-RC2.jar!/logback.xml]
15:16:00,895 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Resource [logback.xml] occurs multiple times on the classpath.
15:16:00,895 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Resource [logback.xml] occurs at [jar:file:/opt/pdi-cosmos/cosmos-admin/lib/play_2.10-2.2.2-RC2.jar!/logback.xml]
15:16:00,895 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Resource [logback.xml] occurs at [jar:file:/opt/pdi-cosmos/cosmos-api/lib/com.typesafe.play.play_2.10-2.2.2-RC2.jar!/logback.xml]
15:16:00,916 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.ConfigurationWatchList@3621767f - URL [jar:file:/opt/pdi-cosmos/cosmos-admin/lib/play_2.10-2.2.2-RC2.jar!/logback.xml] is not of type file
15:16:01,071 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - debug attribute not set
15:16:01,076 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - About to instantiate appender of type [ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender]
15:16:01,086 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Naming appender as [STDOUT]
15:16:01,119 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.NestedComplexPropertyIA - Assuming default type [ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder] for [encoder] property
15:16:01,182 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.RootLoggerAction - Setting level of ROOT logger to ERROR
15:16:01,182 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [STDOUT] to Logger[ROOT]
15:16:01,183 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - End of configuration.
15:16:01,186 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.JoranConfigurator@4eeaa79c - Registering current configuration as safe fallback point

[[37minfo[0m] play - database [default] connected at jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/cosmos
[[37minfo[0m] play - Application started (Prod)
Persistent Storage Terminated. Not changing anything...
```

Comment: I assume your running `puppet apply` on the manifest. try `puppet apply -v -d /path/to/manifest` and supply  the output.

Comment: yes this is the output using --debug --verbose options.

Added major output information

Answer (score 0):

This version of Cosmos was deprecated in favour of a new one based on Openstack's Sahara. Please check for it at [FIWARE's Catalogue](http://catalogue.fiware.org/enablers/bigdata-analysis-cosmos).